# tmux server ignores sourcing configuration file

Tags: tmux

I added a `bind p paste-buffer` line to my `~/.tmux.conf` file for testing purposes and then sourced the configuration with `:source ~/.tmux.conf` command. Everything worked and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> pasted my buffer. Then I removed the `bind p paste-buffer` line from `~/.tmux.conf` file and again executed the `:source ~/.tmux.conf` command, but still <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> pastes my buffer. Are there certain situations when `:source-file ~/.tmux.conf` does not work and one needs to restart `tmux` server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key-binding is still in place in the running `tmux` instance since it was never explicitly unbound.

Use `unbind-key p` for that.

Sourcing the configuration file does not magically reset the active configuration, and we are happy it doesn't because that would make it really tricky to source one configuration file from another.